# How can i fill 1D array from 2D array and how can i sort 1D array?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq

hanks everybody to help my idiot problem (look my before post:) ) . But i exactly need below. I should fill 1 dimentional array from legth of per cell Datatable. and sort 1D array linq and also without linq

```
 int[][] lengths;

            using (DataTable table = GetTable())
            {
                lengths = (from DataRow row in table.Rows
                           select
                           (from DataColumn col in table.Columns
                            select row[col].ToString().Length).ToArray()).ToArray();
            }

            int[] Sortedlist;
            foreach (int[] row in lengths)
            {
                Sortedlist = row; ---- I NEED HELP !!!!
            }

            foreach (int item in Sortedlist)
            {
                item.Sort(); ----- I NEED HELP!!!
            }

My Data: 

       static DataTable GetTable()
        {
            //
            // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
            //
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

            //
            // Here we add five DataRows.
            //
            table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

            return table;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean . You have an int[][] datastructure(from the main linq query).
Your req is to convert it into a int[] structure and then sort it using linq and also sort it using Array.sort.
This should do it

```
   int[] UnSortedlist = lengths.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
            int[] sortedListLinq = UnSortedlist.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
            Array.Sort(UnSortedlist);
            int[] sortedListnonLinq = UnSortedlist;
```

Comment: i like :  Array.Sort(UnSortedlist);
            int[] sortedListnonLinq = UnSortedlist;

But how can i use Descending like Reverse() method?